# How to hide the background underneath the border

Tags: css

I need to modify a website to make the clickable zone of all links bigger for mobile devices. I gave all links a transparent `border` and a negative `margin` of the same size, to not affect the text-flow. Now this works like a charm. But not on elements that have a background. The background spreads out to the transparent border. This is behaviour seams to be consistent among all browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/hq65C/1/ here a other example: http://jsfiddle.net/DytDA/

Why is this? I was always thinking that the border is outside of the element. How could I fix this. (I need a solution that does not require to modify the HTML).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

How about `background-clip: padding-box;`?

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/meo/DytDA/1/)**

Comment: this is the solution i was looking for, thank you. Maybe you want to append this link your solution, to make it perfect ;) http://jsfiddle.net/meo/DytDA/1/

Comment: Great, thanks. It has pretty good support too (IE9+): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

i think that if the border were outside the element, the behaviour you are behind (that clicking on the border behaves as clicking inside the element) wouldn't work either

if the background-image is not repeated, you can set background-position x position to the same amount that your border width. else, you can also try setting the border-color to the same as the color behind the element, but if it is an image, good luck

Comment: thanks but the background image is a sprite so i really need a other solution.

Answer (score 0):

CSS `background` fills the area of the `border`, with the `border-color` layering over this.

As you have a transparent `border`, it is displaying the `background-color` behind it.

With plain HTML/CSS, I'm not sure there is a way around this.

This jsFiddle demostrates this:

http://jsfiddle.net/hq65C/8/

Comment: ok the background position does not change, but it shows more of the background: http://jsfiddle.net/DytDA/ :/

Comment: Yes thats because the red is not covering it. It's there behind the red in the first anchor. Sorry I'm not sure you can achieve what your after with just HTML/CSS. There may be javascript/jquery solutions perhaps

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<a href="#"><span style="background: red">link</span></a> test test test <br/>
test test test
```

notice: the span means an inline element with another style (other CSS values). other that div which will force a new block.

Comment: like i wrote in my Question, modifying the DOM is not a option.