# css nearhover solution

Tags: css

While creating my  webapplication I wanted a hover action on some element. I noticed it would be nice to have the hover trigger whenever you get near the element (instead of the second you cross the border. First it made me think of [hoverintent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) but that only checks to see if your mousemovement is actually intending to hover the element (ie waiting a bit til the mouse slows down).

After a bit of searching I found 2 solutions and the latter made me think of a 3rd.

1st one is in my opinion the least elegant:
Create a mousemove event get the mouse position and detect which element is in the neighbourhood and trigger its hover action.

2nd:
Create an invisible element in the to-be-hovered element which is bigger (also lower z-index) thus making it trigger the hover of the main element while still physically outside but 'near' the element.

3rd:
This is almost the same as 2, but uses the :after (or :before) psuedoelement.

```
element:after{
    position:absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 120%;
    width: 120%;
    top:-10%;
    left:-10%;
}
```

edit:
[as mentioned by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806036/css-nearhover-solution/7806270#7806270) [lollero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603568/lollero)
[solution](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/t857Y/1/) 4:(<--lollero's jsfiddle link)
the element can get a padding and then equivalent negative margin.

```
img { padding: 20px; margin: -20px; }
```

could also be:

```
.element { padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; margin: 0px -20px 0px -20px; }
```

#### What are your ideas on the 3(now 4) solutions and do you maybe have another solution?

What i'm aiming for is something that can be implemented with affecting as little as possible of the surrounding.

[jsfiddle demo simple version of what i want to achieve](http://jsfiddle.net/yourilima/mKHDc/4/) button is just a control to the element.

Comment: I don't have another solution, but I suggest you rethink the whole idea. Making the hover-spot bigger lets the user think that the clickable area is bigger too, which might end up in 'empty' clicks. That's not very elegant or user-friendly imo.

Comment: Its beceause when I hover a few controlls appear outside the element. thus making it a bit annoying having to move into the element to make em visible and then out again to click on them. I'm also playing with what the best distance would be.  but you are right, in a lot of situations this damages user experience. just so far i dont think it does in my situation.

Comment: could you give us an example? maybe there's still a totally different approach to solve your problem!

Answer (score 2):

So, still not all that clear what the big picture is.. You could do something like this if i understood correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/t857Y/

Same thing but I gave the `img` z-index value. 
http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/t857Y/1/

Essentially the element has a padding and then equivalent negative margin.

```
img { padding: 20px; margin: -20px; }
```

could also be:

```
.element { padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; margin: 0px -20px 0px -20px; }
```

---

And if you dont mind it pushing away other elements around it.. then add just the padding.

Comment: I like your solutions. didnt think of that.. would you mind if i mention this in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with a border: http://jsfiddle.net/YHQJ9/

```
a {
  position: relative;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  margin: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

So you can still use the padding to style your element a little. You have to use position relative and give your element a z index, in order to make it work properly for inline content.

But i would not recommend doing this. Its not the behavior that a user would expect. It could feel strange or even buggy to the user...

Its a good idea for the iPad for example. Sometimes links that are inline are a little hard to click, with this trick its makes it easy to touch it.

Comment: Sure. Though I'd like to note that using padding and margin doesn't really take away ability to use padding... For example `padding: 10px; margin: -5px` and in here there is 5px padding.

Comment: yes sure its makes it just more complicated... i like simple things :) Used this trick not long agao; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473200/transparent-border-expands-background-color-image

Comment: True dat. What do you mean that on ipad links are little hard to click sometimes?

Comment: when the inline text is small, or sometimes buttons are just to small to be clicked with a finger...