# How can I make my image-border appear outside of background-color

Tags: css, html, border, footer

http://jsfiddle.net/efDuN/

I am trying to create a footer with a top image border, and a background color. However, the image has transparency in it that shows the background color beyond the edges. The height of the footer is in Ems whereas the height of the border-image is 46 pixels.

How can I get the border to appear outside of the background color, while maintaining its flexibility (Ems)?

```
<div id="footer">

<br>
<p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
<br>
```

```
body {
background-color: black;
}

#footer {
 border-style: solid; border-width: 46px 0px 0px; 
-moz-border-image: url("http://i272.photobucket.com/albums/jj180/niahcx/web/smalllace_zpscffc6b3e.png") 46 1 0 0 repeat; 
-webkit-border-image: url("http://i272.photobucket.com/albums/jj180/niahcx/web/smalllace_zpscffc6b3e.png") 46 1 0 0 repeat; 
-o-border-image: url("http://i272.photobucket.com/albums/jj180/niahcx/web/smalllace_zpscffc6b3e.png") 46 1 0 0 repeat; 
border-image: url("http://i272.photobucket.com/albums/jj180/niahcx/web/smalllace_zpscffc6b3e.png") 46 1 0 0 fill repeat;

background-color: pink;
background-repeat: repeat;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
height: 6em; 
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [How to hide the background underneath the border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473200/transparent-border-expands-background-color-image)

Use `background-clip: padding-box` to keep the background color from bleeding into your border image.

http://jsfiddle.net/efDuN/13/

Comment: The other answers work well, but this seems like the simplest. I have to disagree that this is a duplicate

Comment: If you know a question is a duplicate of another, **please vote to close it as such**

Comment: Thank you Zach. Looks like you've done this already but I cannot delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another div to the footer that will contain all footer content.

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_content">
        <br>
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
        <br>
    </div>
</div><!--footer-->
```

Keep border on a footer and make footer_content div have pink background.

http://jsfiddle.net/efDuN/11/

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution which can also be easily edited.

All, you need to do is modify your HTML as such:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footerTop"></div>
    <div id="footerBottom">
        <br/>
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and add the following CSS :

```
#footerTop {
    width: 100%;
    /*background-color:Orange;*/
    /*border-top-image*/
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 46px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-image: url("http://i272.photobucket.com/albums/jj180/niahcx/web/smalllace_zpscffc6b3e.png") 46 1 0 0 repeat;
    -webkit-border-image: url("http://i272.photobucket.com/albums/jj180/niahcx/web/smalllace_zpscffc6b3e.png") 46 1 0 0 repeat;
    -o-border-image: url("http://i272.photobucket.com/albums/jj180/niahcx/web/smalllace_zpscffc6b3e.png") 46 1 0 0 repeat;
    border-image: url("http://i272.photobucket.com/albums/jj180/niahcx/web/smalllace_zpscffc6b3e.png") 46 1 0 0 fill repeat;
}

#footerBottom {
    background-color: pink;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 6em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You can take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/dLUmm/

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Could you please explain the reason for the downvote?

Comment: This adds an additional HTML element that does not serve any structural purpose. The OP's question was regarding the use of CSS's border-image property.

Comment: The OP's question does not ask for a CSS border-image only solution. The OP has only asked for a solution. There is no inkling of 'only a CSS border-image-related answer wanted' in the question. The OP asked for a solution. My answer IS a solution albeit just a different approach from yours. Just because I have implemented it in a different fashion (in comparison to you answer), doesn't mean my answer is wrong or incorrect. So the downvote is not really required. But if that pleases you giant-sized ego and makes you feel good about yourself even for a little while, well then be happy!!!!

Comment: No problems at all. Happy to give you the only moment where you feel good about yourself!!!